# Which user-agent string is most optimal for use in ADM or similar download management applications?

Tags: downloading, media-files, download-manager, user-agent-string

I thoroughly comprehend **what** a user-agent string is, and **how** to spoof/parse them.  What I can't seem to find in the endless sea of search results that all speak about the same two aforementioned points is: **which** should I use?  For my use-case, it'd be specific to using [Advanced Download Manager & Torrent downloader (ADM)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dv.adm) on an Android device for downloading videos.  Which — if any — would be optimal in terms of file accessibility, speed, stability, etc?  Which should be avoided in the practical sense?  I understand this is likely dependent upon the web developer's end, but in a more general sense I'm wondering if the UA has any inherent impact to these factors, if all else remains the same?

EDIT: to clarify, from my observations the typical use cases seem qualitative — whether a particular file is served or not, i.e., `true|false`.  I'm wanting to confirm there are no other functional impacts from the user's standpoint aside from whether a file is made available or not (disregarding build variants based on UA, so assuming for example's sake that they are identical).

Comment: This question seems to target a specific Android app but you only denote it's short name. In case you refer to an app please always include the full name and a link to a store where it is available. Regarding your question: A user agent string is just a string. A server can use it or not.

Comment: @Robert I've edited to include the link to application.  Regarding the use case, the application settings include a list of browsers and a "custom" entry specific to the app itself (listed as "ADM", have not parsed the string myself to see what the difference is).  Am I to understand that the only functional differences are qualitative (pass/fail for server to serve file), nothing else?

Comment: A user-agent string is just one of the many [http headers](http://myhttpheader.com) your browser sends to the http server when requesting a webpage. Usually it contains information about your browser version and operating system. I don't think it has much to do with file accessibility, speed or stability. The only reason one would want to fake user-agent can be due to compatibility reasons, or in some cases privacy reasons (but the latter is a different debatable topic). So your definition of "optimal" is quite unclear here. Keep using the default one, unless you have a specific problem.

Comment: Well, honestly, while it *might* be possible, a server discriminating download speed/stability based on user agents seems a bizarre idea.